# i have dt column from 2018-10-01 and 2018-10-31 and i want to display in one column

Tags: sql

```
+——————————————————————————+—————————+————————————+—————————————————+
| dt                       | user_id | game_name  | totalgameplayed |
+——————————————————————————+—————————+————————————+—————————————————+
| 2018-10-01 to 2018-10-31 | 1111111 | fruit chop |                 |
+——————————————————————————+—————————+————————————+—————————————————+
```

I want to calculate from this:

```
dt2018-10-01 to 2018-10-31
```

and display `game_name` count.

Comment: provide your sample data and expected output in tabular form.

Comment: like dt 2018-10-01 to 2018-10-31 i want to display in dt column and i want to count how played fruit chop in that month count i want to display

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: i know that but i want display in one dt columns like that for all user's

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: You need to explain in detail what you are trying to da and what the problem is you are facing.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: It's totally unclear to me (and it seems to others as well) what you want to achieve. Is the table you have shown the expected output or the input? If it's the output, what exactly is the input? If it's the input, what exactly is the output? What is the column's data type in the table? Please **[edit]** your question and add a CREATE TABLE statement, some INSERT statements and the output based on that data.